# Log request headers in fastapi dockerrized app

Tags: logging, http-headers, fastapi, datadog, uvicorn

I've got fastapi python app running in containers :
dockerfile :

```
...
CMD ["uvicorn", "--reload", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

application logs are sent to datadog, currently the logs look like this:

```
     10.1.22.251:42324 - "POST /endpoint HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

I want alse reflect request headers in the logs, and not sure  where I should look at, is it something  that can be configured in uvicorn or I need to handle in application code side?

Comment: Which format do you want the headers logged in? Does datadog have an expected format? (usually the different services expect the log entries in a JSON format to do more magic with those values) The Datadog APM might also be an option; it has direct integration with ASGI: https://ddtrace.readthedocs.io/en/stable/integrations.html#asgi

Comment: I'm using python-json-logger  so the logs are sent to the datadog in json format